# Native types and Generics

Tags: generics, reflection, c++-cli, managed, native-code

I want to create a native array and access it managed code. I don't want to re write code to different types, (`int`, `long`, `float`, `double`) therefore tried using generics.

```cpp
typedef int IND;

generic <typename T>
public ref class ntvarray
{
    void *pnt;
    IND sz;

public:
    ntvarray(IND length)
    {
        sz = sizeof(T);
        pnt =  ::operator new(length*sz);
    }

    ~ntvarray()
    {
        ::operator delete(pnt);
    }

    void* pointer()
    {
        return pnt;
    }

    T getitem (IND index)
    {
        //c3229
        return ((T*)pnt)[index];
    }

    void setitem (IND index, T value)
    {
        //c3229
        ((T*)pnt)[index] = value;
    }
};
```

I am getting the error and I know the reason for this error,

> error C3229: `'T *'` : indirections on a generic type parameter are not allowed

However is there a way to do this using generics? Any other way to do this, may be something else other than using generics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do this using generics.  But you can use templates.  This avoids the code duplication, which your question emphasizes, but won't allow run-time instantiation like generics would.

Comment: Actually I want to reuse this class with several types in the managed code without duplication of code. I don't see any other way than generics. However generics doesn't support specialization either. :(

Comment: And the managed code links this code is in c#, which cannot use template classes. 
How C# code, which references to the assembly having the above code will access a template class?

Comment: @Annifer: Yeah, that's unfortunate.  I assume that C# code using this is also generic?  What I'd do is (1) declare a generic `interface class` (2) change this code to a template and make it implement the generic interface (3) make a factory function that takes in a `System.Type` and creates a new matching object (this will cause instantiation of all the template variations).  C# won't care that the class was made with a template, since it knows how to use a generic interface.

Comment: OK! it works! Thanks.
Factory Function does the job.
However it is twice slower as its non- generic version..  as Expected.

Comment: @Annifer: Hopefully only the creation is slow, and then using the interface is very fast?  But yes, calling through an interface can be expected to be slightly slower because it's much more difficult for the JIT compiler to inline.

Comment: Nope. Interface is slow. I am not bothered about creation, since it is one time execution.
I think it is because of the JIT type checks?  
Since native code is involved, I dont think JIT will be able to inline in both non-generic or generic cases?

FYI:  Number of Executions  100000 x 1000
(Non-generic, generic) 15393, 36818 milliseconds.

Comment: @Anniffer: There's no native code except the call to `::operator new` (the rest is just unsafe code, due to pointer arithmetic), so the JIT probably does inline `getitem` and `setitem` in the non-generic case.  Have you compared the speed to a .NET array accessed directly and also through `IList`?

Comment: OK.
(Non-generic, generic, .net array - direct, net array - IList)
(15612,37250,16052,61612)
It's interesting and bizarre, .net arry direct access is almost same as non generic array. How come a direct access of .net array is same as Marshalling? Why IList is unacceptably slow?
Things change when the array size is small (1000 doubles). direct access to .net array is simply fast. This is a OK. But why things are changing when the array is large?

Comment: @Anniffer: Results for very small arrays are probably affected by whether it's in CPU cache.  Non-generic code is converted to MSIL for pointer access, while .NET array becomes MSIL `ldelem` and `stelem` instructions, but both become the exact same machine code.  There is no marshalling here.  I thought that your generic interface and .NET's IList should be the same since they're both generic interfaces.  Wait, did you use generic IList or non-generic IList?  The non-generic one will need boxing and that's why it's slow.